# How can I export to csv with custom column order in Material-React-Table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export-to-csv, material-react-table

How can I export to csv with a users custom column ordering being used?  I've tried using getSortedRowModel but it doesn't work

```
  const handleExportRows = (rows) => {
    csvExporter.generateCsv(rows.map((row) => row));
  };

...

<Button
   disabled={table.getPrePaginationRowModel().rows.length === 0}
   onClick={() =>
     handleExportRows(table.getSortedRowModel().rows)
   }
   startIcon={<FileDownloadIcon />}
   variant="contained"
>
```

this is the csv options being used

```
const csvOptions = {
    fieldSeparator: ',',
    quoteStrings: '"',
    decimalSeparator: '.',
    showLabels: true,
    useBom: false,
    useKeysAsHeaders: false,
    headers: columns.map((c) => c.header),
  };
```